# XtuService consumes a lot of memory and CPU

Tags: windows-11, asus, armoury-crate

I have a rog m16 laptop. there is a background service named xtuservice. Recently, when I reinstalled the armory crate app, it started to use a lot of resources. Although I've read articles about it, I'm still not sure how to remove it. It is important to mention that sometimes I see more than four or five processes with the same name in task manager.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.minitool.com/news/xtuservice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XTUOCDriverService was failing in my case and was causing infinity loops, so I disabled it and the problem was fixed.

Disable the following service

[image: XTUOCDriverService, xtuservice]

Note: I'm not sure if stopping XTUservice is 100% safe, but in my case, since it always tries to start, I decided to stop it.